# Unable to update PIA from version 75 to 77

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, vpn

[Private Internet Access](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/) is one of my VPN providers.

I am unable to update [PIA](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/) from version 75 to 77 with the following error.

I tried uninstalling [PIA](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/) v75 and running the installer again with the same result.

Error messages follow:

```
Installing files...
mv: cannot move '/home/pia/.pia_install.4881/installer_linux/deploy_files' to '/opt/pia': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/opt/pia/openvpn_launcher.32': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/opt/pia/openvpn_launcher.64': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/opt/pia/root_runner/root_runner.32': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/opt/pia/root_runner/root_runner.64': No such file or directory
Installing dependencies...
Running: sudo apt-get install -y libxss1 libappindicator1 gconf2 net-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gconf2 is already the newest version (3.2.6-3ubuntu6).
libxss1 is already the newest version (1:1.2.2-1).
net-tools is already the newest version (1.60-26ubuntu1).
libappindicator1 is already the newest version (12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 273 not upgraded.
./installer_linux/installer.rb:167:in `expand_path': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
    from ./installer_linux/installer.rb:167:in `install'
    from ./installer_linux/installer.rb:187:in `<main>'
```

---

I noticed I do not have an `/opt` directory present on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was real simple, to create that directory, that is:

```
sudo mkdir /opt
```

And then run the installer again.

---

Obviously, the installer does not count on such a case, where `/opt` directory is not present on the system.